# How do I pass values from grails back to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

I have a feeling that the answer to this is easy but I can't seem to get it yet...

I have a Javascript function that calls an action in a Groovy class via a remoteFunction. Now, I need to return the value from the action class back to the Javascript function for further processing. It looks something like this:

```
// sample js function in the gsp file
function setPrev() {
   ...
   var tmp = $remoteFunction(action: 'someaction', params: ...)
   ...
}
```

In the controller, the action would look something like this:

```
def someaction = {
   ...
   def retVal = Somedomain.anobject // 1:m relationship so there's a hasMany = [anobject...] in Somedomain
   ...
   return retVal
}
```

Now, when it returns to tmp, it's [object object]. Is there a way for me to get, at the very least, [anobject1, anobject2, ..., anobjectn] as the value of tmp? I've even tried json but it's still [object object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is quite easy

```
 return retVal as JSON
```

Just remember to import org.grails.converters.JSON (I think it is)

Comment: hi, ya, i did this but when i printed out tmp, it's [object object]... not the json representation...

Comment: hi, that's more a javascript issue.. if you use FireBug in FireFox (and you should!), try to write console.debug(tmp) in your javascript code. 
To get your data, you should write tmp.variableName.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

Actually, I've been looking at the DOM via Firebug but i'm a little lost there as well. Anyway, as for the tmp.variableName, that's a little tricky, I think... I can't seem to figure out what the variableName is. retVal is, when I print out the class type in groovy, of type PersistentSet... in this case, it should look like [object1: 1, object2: 2, ...] So should I reference it as tmp.object1? When I did, it told me that it was "undefined" but when I look at retVal, it does have [object1: 1, object2: 2, ...] as the content...

Comment: in firebug you could also try console.dir(tmp) - this will print the structure and variables of your json